# What the author is trying to say in this paragraph?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Consider the following paragraph:

> The possibility that such rents were important is, I think, reinforced by many of the institutional features of the colonial era: the carving up of the Third World by the European powers, and the frequent granting of exclusive trading rights to monopoly companies.

What is the relation between the two sentences separated by a colon? What the author is trying to say?

(Just note that by "rent", the author means [economic rent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_rent).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, What follows the colon is a description of what precedes it, or is at the very least related to it.

In your paragraph,

> the carving up of the Third World by the European powers, and the
>   frequent granting of exclusive trading rights to monopoly companies.

are intended to be

> some of the many institutional features of the colonial era

Here are [some](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/colon/2/colon-between-independent-clauses/) [references](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/colons_extend_a_sentence.htm) on the extension of sentences by using colons.

Comment: Still couldn't get what the whole text means. What is the meaning of this part: "The possibility that such rents were important is reinforced by many of the institutional features of the colonial era."

Comment: It means that the author _thinks_ that said institutional features of the colonial era(like _carving up of the Third World by European powers_) strengthen the importance of such rents(_economic rent_, like you said)